# Highlight values with a rectangle/shaded area in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Hello everyone I have the following example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


set.seed(78)
vector <- runif(n = 360, min = -4, max = 4)
dates <- seq(as.Date('1980-01-01'), length.out=360, by='1 month')


df <- data.frame(dates = dates, index = vector)

#Aqui ya se hace la diferencia entre positivo y negativo con color
df$colour <- ifelse(df$index < 0, "Negative","Positive")
ggplot(df,aes(dates,index,label=""))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="identity",aes(fill = colour))+
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Valor", values=c(Positive="firebrick",Negative="dodgerblue4"))+
  ggtitle("Index")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  xlab("Year") + ylab("S.D.")
```

And I generate this image:

[image]

What I want to do is highlight a specific time interval with a square or something, so it can look like this:

[image]

As I said, it is not necessary have to be a solid line it could be a shaded area, does anyone know how I can make this?

Comment: perhaps `geom_rect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dww mentioned `geom_rect` works. Adding the below layer:

```
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = as.Date('1993-06-01'),
      xmax = as.Date('1994-11-01'),
      ymin = min(index),
      ymax = 0
    ),
    fill = NA,
    color = "black",
    size = 2
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This would create an open box, but addition of an additional point at the end could close it if you needed:

```
+ geom_path(data=data.frame(y=c(0,-2,-2,0), x=as.Date('1980-01-01')+30*c(40,40,60,60)),
            mapping=aes(x=x,y=y))
```

[image]

The major hurdle was to recognize that the x-axis was Date classed.